# Convert Table/Column names into Pascal Case with EF T4 Template

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, code-generation, t4

I followed the instructions [here](https://khalidk7.wordpress.com/2014/04/21/entity-framework-ef-t4-template-modification-to-output-pascalcasing-database-objects/) and [here](https://github.com/TheTrigger/EF6-T4-CamelCase) to convert the names of my entities and their properties to Pascal Case. Everything looks fine, the the classes are generated with the right names, and the project is complied without any errors, but when I run my the application, I get an error saying that

> The entity type [...] is not part of the model for the current
>   context.

And, the EF designer still shows the entities with their original names from the database. How can I add some code to the T4 template to make sure the .edmx file is also generated with the correct class/entity names? Or, is there any other the solution?

Comment: How can we know without seeing what your code looks like or what code is generated?

Comment: @DavidG, the code doesn't matter here. As I mentioned, the code works and the entity classes are generated correctly. The problem is that changing the entity class names, using the T4 template, doesn't seem to be enough. However, the code is provided in the GitHub link I have in my post.